# MySQL LEFT JOIN Problem - Missing LEFT column

Tags: mysql, left-join

I'm having problems with an SQL query used to display custom profile fields and any (optional) corresponding values.

Here is the SQL query I'm using:

```
SELECT pf.`id`, pf.`name`, pv.`value` FROM `profile_fields` AS pf
LEFT JOIN `profile_values` AS pv ON (pf.`id` = pv.`field_id`)
WHERE (pf.`site_id` = '0' OR pf.`site_id` = '%d') AND (pv.`user_id` = '%d' OR pv.`user_id` IS NULL)
ORDER BY pf.`order` ASC
```

The problem I'm having is that any columns with no corresponding `profile_values` records are not shown at all, when they should show, but just with an empty value.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try moving the profile values conditions to the JOIN statement:

```
 SELECT pf.`id`, pf.`name`, pv.`value` FROM `profile_fields` AS pf
 LEFT JOIN `profile_values` AS pv ON (
         pf.`id` = pv.`field_id`  AND 
         (pv.`user_id` = '%d' OR pv.`user_id` IS NULL)
  )
 WHERE (pf.`site_id` = '0' OR pf.`site_id` = '%d')
 ORDER BY pf.`order` ASC
```

Comment: Many thanks - that did the trick! Never knew I was able to add that sort of thing in an "ON" clause!

Comment: Shouldn't the ... OR ... pv.user_id IS NULL) part of the original query take care of showing the profile_fields without all optional profile_values available?

Comment: That's what I thought, but it didn't for some reason. It works with Eran's code however, so I probably put it in the wrong place.

Comment: You can probably get rid of the 'OR pv.user_id IS NULL' after you move the condition into the join condition.